# How to grep on a file owned by nobody?

Tags: permissions, openvpn, grep

I have a `/etc/openvpn/test.txt` file with the following status and a single word content "test":

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody root  173 Jan 25 21:48 test.txt
```

When I try to grep on it I get a permission denied error.

```
/etc/openvpn/test.txt | grep -c "test"
```

results in:

```
-bash: /etc/openvpn/consumption.txt: Permission denied
0
```

If I try to run grep with sudo as nobody I still get the same error:

```
/etc/openvpn/test.txt | sudo -u nobody grep -c "abs"
```

results in:

```
-bash: /etc/openvpn/consumption.txt: Permission denied
0
```

When I change the owner of the `test.txt` to root, grep performs as expected.

But I have to keep it as owned by nobody because it is supposed to be read and written to from a client-disconnect openvpn script. I am adviced to run openvpn as nobody for security reasons. Pleaes advise me to handle the situation.

This `/etc/openvpn/test.txt | grep -c "test"` command has to be run in client disconnect script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file in question has `rw-r--r--` permissions, which means it can be **read** by everyone. Only `nobody` can **write** it, but that's irrelevant in this case, as you don't need to write to the file.

The message `Permission denied` appears because you use the wrong command.

`/etc/openvpn/test.txt | grep -c "test"` means that you tell the system to **execute** the file `/etc/openvpn/test.txt` **as a program**, and feed the **output** of that program to the `grep` command.

Because the file `/etc/openvpn/test.txt` lacks the **execute** permission (it has only **read** permission for everybody and **write** permission for `nobody`), the system can't execute it and you get the message `Permission denied`. So there's no output from this command (the error message goes to *standard error* and not *standard output*, therefore you see it on the screen) and `grep` receives an **empty** input, so it displays `0` as a result.

This command is wrong. I assume the file `/etc/openvpn/test.txt` is **not** a program that can be executed, but it's just a text file which you want to be **read** by grep. In that case, you should use the following command:

```
grep -c "test" /etc/openvpn/test.txt
```

It means run the program `grep`, and have that program **read** the file `/etc/openvpn/test.txt`.